Vectors and Physics history
I got a very thorough and intuitive understanding of calculus and it's introduction in physics in the book called "Infinite Powers". What's a similar resource that can be used for understanding of vectors in physics

Please give the complete reference :
"Infinite Powers: How Calculus Reveals The Secrets Of The Universe"
Steven Strogatz, Mariner Books

You can see :

Michael Crowe, A History of Vector Analysis (1967).

We have to take into account some "precursors", like the representation of the parallelogram of the velocities and of the forces, already present into ancient Greek science (see the pseudo-Aristotle, Mechanica) and some attempts by Leibniz with his Analysis situs.
The key achievement was the geometrical representation of complex numbers, discovered independently in 1831 by Wessel, Gauss, Argand, etc.
Then we have William Rowan Hamilton with the quaternions and finally the modern system of vector analysis developed by Josiah Willard Gibbs with his lectures of 1881 and 1884 [published as E.B.Wilson, Vector Analysis, a text-book for the use of students of Mathematics and Physics, founded upon the Lectures of J.Willard Gibbs, (1901)] and Oliver Heaviside, with his 1882-83 paper on electromagnetism published on The Electrician.
Also useful, for mathematics and physics in general: Morris Kline, Mathematics and the Physical World (Dover, 1959)

@Shreya Gupta: For links to some freely available original literature from the 1800s to very early 1900s on quaternions (including links to many book reviews), see my History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange answers to Notations for Laplacian: $\nabla^2$ vs. $\Delta$ and What set of criteria led Hamilton to discover the quaternions?
